# Почему Button срабатывает только со второго раза?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

HTML

```
<div class="h_m_search">
            <button onclick="Search()" id="sr" width="50px" height="50px"> 
<img src="img/icon.png" alt=""></button>
            <input type="text" id="inp">
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#sr {
width:100px;
position:static;
max-width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 100%;
border:none;
background-color:#ba0000; 
box-shadow: -1px 2px 10px black;
```

}

```
#inp{
margin-top: 15px;
height: 30px;
border-radius: 100px;
border:2px solid #ba0000;
background:white url(img/icon-red.png) no-repeat 5%;
text-align: center;
display: none;
```

}

JavaScript

```
function Search() {
var sr = document.getElementById("sr");
var inp = document.getElementById("inp");
if( inp.style.display !== "none" )
{
    sr.style.position = "static"
    inp.style.display = "none"  
    sr.style.width = "50px"
    sr.style.height = "50px"

}

else{

    sr.style.width = "28px"
    sr.style.height = "28px"
    sr.style.position = "relative"
    sr.style.right = "-35px"
    sr.style.top = "1px"
    inp.style.display = "inline-block"

 }
 }
```

Comment: Потому что display в css-файле и display во встроенных стилях элемента это два разных display. Если вы хотите учитывать display прописанный в css-файле, используйте getComputedStyle

Answer (score 1):

для получения стила элемента

```
var srStyle = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(inp, null) : inp.currentStyle;
```

и из srStyle ты можешь  получения srStyle.display

```
function Search() {
var sr = document.querySelector("#sr");
var inp = document.querySelector("#inp");
var display = window.getComputedStyle(inp).display

var srStyle = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(inp, null) : inp.currentStyle;

console.log(srStyle.display)

if( srStyle.display !== "none" )
{ 
  sr.style.position = "static"
    inp.style.display = "none"  
    sr.style.width = "50px"
    sr.style.height = "50px" 
} else{  
    sr.style.width = "28px"
    sr.style.height = "28px"
    sr.style.position = "relative"
    sr.style.right = "-35px"
    sr.style.top = "1px"
    inp.style.display = "inline-block"

 }
 }
```